# Asymptotics of tail function of product of 2 iid gamma variables

Tags: integration, asymptotics, self-learning, gamma-distribution, distribution-tails

Suppose we have an integral of this form:
$\overline F(x)=\frac{\beta^{2\alpha-1}}{\Gamma^2(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta(\frac{x}{y}+y)}dy$, where $\beta>0, \alpha>0$ and $x>0$.
I want to show that it asymptotically converges to a function of this type:
$\overline F(x) =  \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}\beta^{2(\alpha-1)+\frac{1}{2}}}{\Gamma^2(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-\frac{3}{4}}e^{-2\beta x^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ 
The only method I came up with was the saddle point method, but unfortunately it didn't work.
Maybe anyone has some ideas?

Comment: Making the substitution $y=\sqrt x t;\,dy=\sqrt xdt;\,t\in[0;\infty)$, you are getting $\displaystyle e^{-\beta(\frac{x}{y}+y)}=e^{-\beta\sqrt x(t+\frac{1}{t})}$; then apply the saddle point (Laplace) method.

Comment: This is just a coefficient; the integration goes with respect to $t$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\beta(\frac{x}{y}+y)}\,dy=2 \sqrt{x}\, K_1\left(2 \beta \sqrt{x} \right)$$
$$\overline F(x)=\frac{2 \beta   }{\Gamma (\alpha )^2}\,x^{\alpha -\frac{1}{2}}\, K_1\left(2 \beta \sqrt{x} \right)$$

Now, uwe the asymptotics of the modified Bessel function of the second kind; it then should be simple.

Answer (score 1):

[Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) applies to $\int \exp [\beta f(y)] dy $ where $f(y)$ has a global maximum inside the integration interval.

In our case $$f(y)=-\frac{x}{y} -y $$ which has a global maximum at $y_0 = \sqrt{x}$ , with $f(y_0)=-2 \sqrt{x}$ and $f''(y_0)= -2 \,x^{-1/2}$

Hence

$$
\begin{align}
\overline F(x)&=\frac{\beta^{2\alpha-1}}{\Gamma^2(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta(\frac{x}{y}+y)}dy\\
&=\frac{\beta^{2\alpha-1}}{\Gamma^2(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\beta f(y)}dy\\
&\approx \frac{\beta^{2\alpha-1}}{\Gamma^2(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1} \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{ \beta | f''(y_0)|}} \exp(\beta f(y_0))\\
&= \frac{\beta^{2\alpha-3/2}}{\Gamma^2(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-3/4} \sqrt{\pi} \exp(-2\beta x^{1/2})
\end{align}
$$

Caveat: this is asymptotically correct for $\beta \to +\infty$ and fixed $x$.